# 'ng test' failing after upgrading to @Angular/cli :1.1.0

Tags: angular, testing, angular-cli

**Angular version that I installed:**

[image: Angular version that I installed]

**Errors that are being displayed when running ng test:**

[image: Errors that are being displayed trying to run ng test]

**devDependencies:**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.63",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.75",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "electron": "^1.7.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4",
    "wallaby-webpack": "0.0.34"
```

Comment: Did you by any chance had the beta version before the upgrade? How did you upgrade the CLI's version?

Comment: Global package:

1) npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
2) npm cache clean
3) npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Local project package:

1) npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
2) npm install

Comment: @Sathvik whats your version of npm ? i got same issue after upgrade on npm@5

Comment: @Michal
Currently it is 4.4.4 . Its asking me to update to 5.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some angular module was not properly installed. Delete package-lock.json if you have it, update to latest angular, and `npm install`.

Comment: I tried everything seems like nothing is working .
The code is compiling properly but the tests are failing

Comment: Try removing your node_modules and reinstalling.

Comment: I tried removing node modules and reinstalling again but its not working . Only ng test is not working. ng serve works perfectly fine.
I guess the problem is with the new angular version that was released just 5 days back

Comment: @ Omri

Any idea on how to resolve  typescript's typings error ?